# The Scroll Detect Multiply when it goes to bottom And the return data disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The scroll detect multiply at bottom and the return data first it comes then disappear on next scroll however i have put append case in it. I want to display timeline to get data from database on scroll down. It comes with the value of start input hidden. It goes and tells database to display that record. But scroll detects multiply on scroll first and then .append to display the record what it send the start value.

```
function yHandler(){
    // Watch video for line by line explanation of the code
    // http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eziREnZPml4
    var wrap = document.getElementById('midcontent');
    var contentHeight = wrap.offsetHeight;
    var yOffset = window.pageYOffset; 
    var y = yOffset + window.innerHeight;
    if(y > contentHeight){
        var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
        // Create our XMLHttpRequest object
        var hr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
        // Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
        var url = "loadtimeline.php"; 
        //var cityval = document.getElementById("city").value;
        var vars = 'start='+start;
        //"fullname="+fullname+"email="+email&+"password="+password&+"purpose="+purpose&+"agencyname="+agencyname&+"country="+country&+"city="+city; 
        hr.open("POST", url, true); 
        // Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
        hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
        // Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
        hr.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) { 
                            //Add Class
                            var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
                            iDiv.id = 'block';
                            iDiv.className = 'block';
                            document.getElementById("datapost").appendChild(iDiv);
                            // Now create and append to iDiv
                            var innerDiv = document.createElement('div');
                            innerDiv.className = 'block-2';
                            theParent = document.getElementById("datapost");
                            theKid = document.createElement("div");
                            theParent.appendChild(theKid);
                            var var1 = document.getElementById("start").value;
                            var var2 = 10;
                            var var3 = Number(var1) + Number(var2); 
                            //var var3  =  +var1 + +var2 
                            //var3 = parseInt(var1,10) + var2; 
                            document.getElementById("start").value=var3;
        var return_data = hr.responseText; 
        //document.getElementById("datapost").innerHTML = return_data;
        theParent.innerHTML = return_data;
        } 
    } 
    // Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
    hr.send(vars); // Actually execute the request
    //document.getElementById("wrap").innerHTML = "";
        // Ajax call to get more dynamic data goes here
        //wrap.innerHTML += '<div class="newData"></div>';
    }
    var status = document.getElementById('status');
    status.innerHTML = contentHeight+" | "+y;
}
window.onscroll = yHandler;
```

The HTML For sending the value of start is:

The Data will return into The div name:

The PHP Query is:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['start'])){
        $start = $_POST['start'];
        $limit = 10;
                //Wall Post
                $wallpostQuery = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `timeline` WHERE `onwall`='".$Record['id']."' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start, $limit");
}
}
?>
```

Comment: The HTML For sending the value of start is: <input type="hidden" id="start" value="3" />

Comment: The Data will return into The div name: <div id="datapost"></div>

Comment: I want to detect If i move mouse wheel or scroll down it just detect one time that the scroll is goes to bottom and start input to get value 10 it takes 20, 30, 40 it detects scroll down several times.